# Using expression bodied properties for constants - is it an anti pattern?

Tags: c#, constants, code-analysis, static-members, anti-patterns

There are a few cases in my codebase where we have a class with a member that always returns a constant. For example, something like this:

```
public interface MyInterface
{
    string SomeString { get; }
}

public class MyClass : MyInterface
{
    public string SomeString => "Hello World!";
}
```

They all have their various use cases.

Now I have added a code analyzer to my project (Microsoft.CodeQuality.Analyzers) and for each of these members, it gets marked with a warning: `warning CA1822: Member SomeString does not access instance data and can be marked as static (Shared in VisualBasic)`

Now, obviously I can't go and mark these as static (since they are required by the interface contract), so I've just been suppressing them:

```
public class MyClass : MyInterface
{
#pragma warning disable CA1822 // Mark members as static
    public string SomeString => "Hello World!";
#pragma warning restore CA1822 // Mark members as static
}
```

There are also some classes that do not implement an interface, it seems to be a bit of an emerging pattern in my codebase.

But now I'm wondering, is this use of expression bodied properties actually doing anything for us? I mean, the analyzer isn't wrong, it's a member that doesn't access anything instance related.

Comment: Presumably because it's implementing an interface, and is accessed through an instance of that interface?

Comment: This is a straightforward bug/limitation of the analyzer, I'd say. It should not warn on interface implementations like this. Personally I have this "recommendation" suppressed *globally*, since I very often implement things that clearly are not static with something that happens to need no object state *right now*, but might in the future. Any "performance gains" from not passing a `this` parameter I'll gladly leave to prove themselves necessary with profiling first. Going back and forth between these is a breaking change, so design goes before implementation here.

Comment: You could use `public string SomeString { get => "Hello World!"; }`...

Comment: Sorry, I clarified in the OP that they're required by the interface contract.

Comment: "Isn't wrong" wouldn't be my first choice to describe the analyzer's view of the situation.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of the analyzer? [There's a test](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/blob/master/src/Microsoft.CodeQuality.Analyzers/UnitTests/QualityGuidelines/MarkMembersAsStaticTests.cs#L410) that it's not raised for things inherited from interfaces. (That test does test methods, not properties, so perhaps that's a limitation of the analyzer). If you are, I'd [raise an issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/issues/new)

Comment: @canton7 there are some that do not implement interfaces, it just seems to be a bit of a pattern around here.

Comment: If you've got a codebase which doesn't implement the rule that "things which can be static must be static" (and consistency is a fair reason not to implement this rule), it doesn't make sense to have that analyzer enabled...? I'd justify disabling it in that case.

Comment: @HereticMonkey: if that *doesn't* trip the analyzer it's an even clearer indication of a bug, as that's semantically equivalent (and produces the exact same IL).

Comment: Do you have any other classes that use the same interface, that don't return a constant? If not, maybe a class attribute would be a better alternative?